# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Media queries

Tags: css

If suppose my device width is 800px, which media query will apply (execute)?

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px){

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px){

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px){

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px){

}
```

If i write the css for the device having screen size is between 768px to 991px and i declare it's css in the media query

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

}
```

then first two media queries will also gets applied how to avoid this.

Comment: Small - Tablets. This is not a Bootstrap question as those breakpoints are not native for Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this three media query for 800px of width 
based on your option

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px){

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px){

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@screen-xs-max: 767px;
@screen-sm-min: 768px;
@screen-sm-max: 991px;
@screen-md-min: 992px;
@screen-lg-min: 1200px;
@screen-md-max: 1199px;

//xs only
@media(max-width: @screen-xs-max) {}

//small and up

@media(min-width: @screen-sm-min) {}
```